# React tutorial example throwing an error in example.js:42

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, reactjs

I am trying to run the example code provided in the React tutorial here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I've downloaded the example code and put it in the htdocs folder of my MAMP install.

I put "http://localhost:3000/public/" into my browser and the title "Comments" and two form fields and a post button appear but no comments. I'm assuming the two comments in the json file should be appearing.

My directory structure is the same as this the git project with the php and json files in the main web folder and the html, css and javascript files in the public folder.

example.js is throwing this error at line 34

/api/comments error Not Found

I thought it might be related to ajax calls on my local machine but I've uploaded the example to a remote server and I'm getting the same error.

jquery.min.js is also throwing an error on line 4:

http://localhost:3000/api/comments?_=1456333607052 404 (Not Found)

[image]

but I'm assuming its because of an upstream error caused by example.js

Am I missing something?

Here is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React Tutorial</title>
        <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
          // To get started with this tutorial running your own code, simply remove
          // the script tag loading scripts/example.js and start writing code here.
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my example.js

```
/**
 * This file provided by Facebook is for non-commercial testing and evaluation
 * purposes only. Facebook reserves all rights not expressly granted.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * FACEBOOK BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
    // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
    // not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
    comment.id = Date.now();
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {author: '', text: ''};
  },
  handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author.trim();
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    this.setState({author: '', text: ''});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your name"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Say something..."
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/api/comments" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Then you have missed something in your code

Comment: I just downloaded the example and copied into the directories. I haven't touched the code.

Comment: Are you running one of the server options to host the comments api?

Comment: I tried it on a remote WAMP stack and on my local MAMP stack. Same error both places. Do I need to do any special server setup? I didn't see any instructions here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Hey, I know this is closed but the same thing happened to me. I fixed it by going into the Python module for the server I was running "server.py" and changed the file read mode from 'r' to 'r+'. Just in case anyone else was having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example servers supplied (See the README.md of the tutorial) have configuration to route the "/api/comments" url, which your standalone servers won't have configured.  Either add that to your server or, simpler, just use one of the example server scripts.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the README file incuded with the tutorial code. You need to run their server implementation to provide the /api/comments endpoint.

Comment: Thanks very much. One other thing I had to do was move the comments.json file into the public folder. I know the readme file says "They all serve static files from `public/`  ", but then why not have the file in there to begin with. Thanks again.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/blob/master/README.md